# Render template using layout from plugin

Tags: grails, layout, gsp

Is it possible to render a template using a layout file from a plugin? If I use the plugin tag, the template is searched form the plugin. E.g.:

```
render (template: "templateFromProject", 
    layout: "layoutFromPlugin")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html), there is a plugin attribute you should be using.

```
render (template: "templateFromProject", layout: "layoutFromPlugin", plugin: 'thePlugin')
```